# How to change value of a input textbox using dom.byid?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to change value of an Input Textbox using several options of dojo but somehow those are not working. On the other hand when I am trying to change the text using document.getElememtById option I am able to do so. Can someone please explain why my dojo options are not working ?

```
   if (response.responseJSON.errorMessage){
                        dom.byId("AuthInfo").innerHTML=response.responseJSON.errorMessage;
                    //  dom.byId("AuthPassowrd").value="";

                    //  domAttr.set("AuthPassowrd", "value", "");
                    //  domConstruct.empty("AuthPassword");
                        document.getElementById("AuthPassword").value="";

                    }
```

and my html code is-

```
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="AuthPassword"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a typo in this code only, but you wrote `"AuthPassowrd"` in stead of `"AuthPassword"`. If it's only the case here (and not the real code), read my original answer.

---

## Original answer

Are you sure you imported the correct modules (`dojo/dom`, `dojo/dom-attr` and `dojo/dom-construct`)? The examples are working fine for me. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/pCKAC/) to show you how it works. You can import these modules by using:

```js
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-construct"], function(dom, domAttr, domConstruct) {
    // Here you can use dom, domAttr and domConstruct
});
```

Make sure the DOM is loaded before you execute your commands. Operations on DOM nodes can only be executed when that part of the DOM (or the entire page) is loaded. Usually you can wait until the DOM is ready with the `dojo/domReady!` plugin:

```js
require(["dojo/domReady!], function() {
    // Will only be executed when the dom is ready
});
```

In your third commented line of code you use `domConstruct.empty("AuthPassword");`. This won't work for clearing the input field but is used to delete all child nodes from a DOM node. The value of the textbox is not a childnode, so it won't work.

Comment: Oh My God !!!....that was actually a typo in my original code .....though thanks for providing info on domConstruct.......

Answer (score 0):

You should just replace this:

```
domAttr.set("AuthPassowrd", "value", "");
```

with:

```
domAttr.set(dom.byId("AuthPassword"), "value", "");
```

Comment: Problem was with the typo.....domAttr.set("AuthPassword", "value", ""); is also working.